# Module is not found in Asp.Net Core 2.0 React Redux web project

Tags: react-redux, asp.net-core-2.0

I created an asp.net core 2.0 project via

```
dotnet new reactredux -n sample
```

then I imported a new module named "react-bootstrap" via npm install

```
 npm install --save @types/react-bootstrap
```

everything is good so far, but if I try to run this project on my local.

I got this error

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

NodeInvocationException: Prerendering failed because of error: Error: Cannot find module "react-bootstrap"
at Object.<anonymous> (e:\git\Sample\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:883:7)
at __webpack_require__ (e:\git\Sample\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (e:\git\Sample\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:327:84)
at __webpack_require__ (e:\git\Sample\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (e:\git\DotNetCoreFans\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:384:66)
at __webpack_require__ (e:\git\Sample\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
at e:\git\Sample\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:66:18
at Object.<anonymous> (e:\git\Sample\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:69:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
Current directory is: e:\git\Sample
```

Does anyone how to fix it?